# Alternate Strings.xml based on Theme

Tags: android, xml, string

My employer has a client in Italy that wants a branded version of our app.  They don't want direct translations of our strings, though, they want their own wordings.

Other than adding the strings to Styles and assigning them by theme, is it possible to point to a different strings.xml based on theme?

If we have no choice but to use styles, is there a way to make formatters work?  a lot of our strings have %s and %d and in my testing, I've been unable to find a way to include the formatted text in the attribute styles call.

Comment: So it's based on a theme, not a language?

Comment: Both, actually. We have translations set for our theme already. They want alternate wordings and translations. Basically I need a separate strings.xml for each theme in each language

Comment: Have you got separated strings.xml for each language? Is that what you need? I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you have/have not ;) Making separate strings.xml for each language is actually really easy, there's a utility in Android Studio. You can learn more there https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: I've got the separate languages. I need to make a separate strings.xml that will be referenced based on theme (not language)

Comment: Strings are on the same level as themes, one cannot depend on the other. Make another flavor of your app and provide alternate resources. See "gradle flavors".

Comment: Eugen, thank you. I haven't heard of flavors yet. I'll look into it. My co-developer had an "ahhhh" moment when I mentioned it so that might be the way to go. Go ahead and post that as an answer